# Distribution of Euclidean distance given two dependent normal distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm stuck on identifying the distribution of
$$
r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}
$$
when $\langle x,y\rangle \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$ are jointly normally distributed.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain some notation in more detail?  Like what is $<x. y>$ or $N$?

Comment: I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: You have already identified it as "the distribution of
$$
r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}
$$
when $\langle x,y\rangle \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$ are jointly normally distributed." What else do you want, specifically? -- Except that you should write $(x,y)$ (the pair) instead of $\langle x,y\rangle$ (the inner product).

Comment: Just to see if I understand the question, are you asking if the distribution can be expressed in terms of other familiar distributions? For example, if $X$ and $Y$ were independent standard normal variables, then $R$ would be a $\chi^2$ variable with $2$ degrees of freedom (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution)? But in your case, you assuming that your variables are some general bivariate normal distribution with a nonzero correlation?